# Mysql Joint joints primary key

Tags: php, mysql, join

I would like to know how can I do joints in this case :

I have a table named : `Table_ref` that contains the name of all the table in the database, with the structure :

```
-----------------------------------------------
| Field       | Type        | Null   | Key    |
-----------------------------------------------
| tbl_name    | varchar(45) |  NO    | PRI    |
| tbl_type    | Tinyint(3)  |  NO    | MUL    |
-----------------------------------------------
```

and forteen other table with names like : `A1`,`B1`, `A2`,`B2` ... with the same structure :

```
-----------------------------------------------
| Field       | Type        | Null   | Key    |
-----------------------------------------------
| id          | int(10)     |  NO    | PRI    |
| itime       | int(10)     |  YES   | MUL    |
| dtime       | int(10)     |  YES   | MUL    |
| src         | varchar(40) |  YES   |        |
| dstname     | varchar(255)|  YES   |        |
-----------------------------------------------
```

The question is how can I do joints in order to extract information where `src='192.168.1.2'` from all the tables.

Comment: I can't help but think that your database design limits your options somewhat...

Comment: To do joints you'll need some weed...

Comment: And now seriously. Do LEFT JOIN for each table and then use WHERE src='192.168.1.2' for each of joined table. Or is this not what you want?

Comment: @Michal isn't there a way to do the all of them with one query ?

Comment: @Moon'sLight - having multiple tables with *same* structure is horrible design. If they differ in name, why don't you just have 1 table and add an extra column that serves that purpose? Then you can do what you want in 1 query.

Comment: @GarethL why do you think it limits my options ?

Comment: @N.B and how do you suggest to merge them into 1 table ?

Comment: How about `UNION` with some kind of marker?

Comment: I'd choose for a single table instead of 14 and if needed use an additional column as an equivalent of different table names.

Comment: @Michal yeah that's right but the problem is that there are new tables everyday , trafic coming directly from two firewall , it's a big database ? how can I change this ?

Comment: Instead of creating new table, insert records?

Comment: The details of how you manage the traffic that's incoming isn't relevant, what is relevant that there exists code that creates tables to store data that comes in. That fact alone means that instead of creating tables - start inserting into existing one(s).

Comment: If I can get you right .. u can more easliy handle it using php code

Comment: @N.B. so you mean I just have to insert all the data in tables into one table using `INSERT` and do a simple query ?

Comment: @dreamCoder I'm already using php code also at the same time , what do you suggest ?

Comment: @Moon'sLight Your database is incorrectly designed if there's a new table added every day. Remember that searching in multiple tables will never be as fast as searching in a single table (even if it's huge).

Comment: @Michel is there a way to change how data are stored ?

Comment: @Moon'sLight I know it will not be good but considering ur current structure .. I can suggest you something like .. `select requiredTables from tabe_ref` then for each table you get Query in loop like `select record from table where src='192.168.1.2'`

Comment: @dreamCoder exactly what I had to do ! you understood my situation and it works , but now that I want to do a pagination and count the most visited sites its becomes very diffcult, because even if I do a LIMIT 0,30 it will give me 10 resultats but for each tables when I only want only 30 resultats then 30 following

Answer (score 0):

This is the combined structure for all your tables

```
-----------------------------------------------
| Field       | Type        | Null   | Key    |
-----------------------------------------------
| id          | int(10)     |  NO    | PRI    |
| itime       | int(10)     |  YES   | MUL    |
| dtime       | int(10)     |  YES   | MUL    |
| src         | varchar(40) |  YES   |        |
| dstname     | varchar(255)|  YES   |        |
| type        | Tinyint(3)  |  NO    | MUL    |
-----------------------------------------------
```

And now you can extract information with a simplist query

```
SELECT
    *
FROM mytable
WHERE src = '192.168.1.2'
```

It will fetch records from every type. If you need information form 
specific type just add another where condition

```
SELECT
    *
FROM mytable
WHERE src = '192.168.1.2'   
AND type = 1
```